# Azure ML add ones error in MS Excel

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am getting this type of error while predicting.

```
Error! 
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "LibraryExecutionError",
            "message": "Module execution encountered an internal library error.",
            "details": [{
                "code": "ColumnNamesMustMatchSchema",
                "target": " (AFx Library)",
                "message": "inputColumnNames: Column names must match the schema. Column names only in input: Date , Day , Temperature , Rainfall , Flyers . Column names only in schema: Date, Day, Temperature, Rainfall, Flyers"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose, extra space in 'Column names only in input' eg. 'Date ' could be an issue.

Comment: How on earth would we know how could be the issue

Comment: Please provide your efforts and what you are getting clearly

Answer (score 0):

Your input is having an extra character in end for each column name. Check the log, it is showing a space before the comma, indicating the mismatch.
Update the input fields (use Trim) if required and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error during the Data Science training.

In my case the issue was because I copied/paste the data.
I had to type manually and make sure there is no space in the begin/end of the word. 
**NitingSingh** (Trim) answer is feasible also.